# Still Can't Get Tic Tac Toe Win Checking Working in Java

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I'm having problems with my Tic Tac Toe code in my Java program. I can't get win checking to work. So far it only works for the diagonal from the top left corner to the bottom right corner. I have all of my win checking code in the `winCheck` method. This is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class TicTacToe {
    public static boolean winCheck(int[][] array, int player){
        int counter = 1;
        for(int i=0; i<array.length-1; i++){
            if(array[i][i] == array[i+1][i+1]){
                counter++;
            }
            if(counter==array.length) {
                System.out.println("Player " + player + " wins.");
                return true;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter board size (e.g. 5): ");
        int size = 0;
        if(console.hasNextInt()){   //If the console has an integer, sets the size
            size = console.nextInt();
        } else {
            while(!console.hasNextInt()){   //If no integer
                console.next(); //Discards bad input
                System.out.print("Invalid input. Enter a whole positive integer: ");
            }
            size = console.nextInt();   //Sets integer once valid input is entered
        }

        int[][] array = new int[size][size];    //Sets the board size by the input (input x input)
        int i=0;    //Initializing "i" for the loops

        do{
            i=1;    //Resets "i" to one
            for(; i<=2; i++){   //For loop repeating for both players 1 and 2
                System.out.print("Player " + i + "'s Move (row,column): ");
                String plyrInput = console.next();
                //errorCheck(plyrInput, console);
                inputParse(plyrInput, i, array);    //Sends player's coordinates, player number, and the array
                if(winCheck(array, i)==true){
                    System.out.print("Game over.");
                    break;
                }
            }

        }while(winCheck(array, i)==false);
        console.close();
    }
    //more methods to play the game...
}
```

Comment: You are missing a lot of cases. First, you are only checking for the diagonal. You should also the `size` rows, `size` columns and the anti-diagonal... .

Comment: @Dici that's OP's question.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza oh, did not read carefully enough. Well, it's a bit of code begging, isn't it ?

Comment: You can't just dump 100+ lines of code into a question and expect someone to figure out what the problem is.  Do some debugging, isolate the problem, construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Dici for me, it's more like a person asking for the algorithm or an idea about how to accomplish this rather than *giving teh codez for free*.

Comment: I only need help with the winCheck method and calling it in the main method. I'm only asking for a solution or idea on fixing the winCheck method so it will check wins correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm just confused on how to get winCheck working.

Comment: "it only works for the diagonal from the top left corner to the bottom right corner": well, that's the only case you have implemented. You need to do the remaining cases in a similar way.

Comment: @Henry again, that's OP's question...

Answer (score 1):

As it is quite an easy thing, I won't give you a working code but rather some hints to write it. I voluntarily used a lot of methods to show you the division of the logic, but you could have much fewer methods in your actual code.

```
public static boolean winCheck(int[][] array, int player){
    boolean win = checkRows (array,player) || checkCols (array,player) ||
        checkDiag(array,player);
    if (win)
        System.out.println("Player " + player + " wins.");
    return win;
}

private static boolean checkRows(int[][] array, int player) {
    for (int i=0 ; i<array.length ; i++)
        if (checkRows(array,player,i))
            return true;
    return false;
}

private static boolean checkCols(int[][] array, int player) {
    for (int i=0 ; i<array.length ; i++)
        if (checkCols(array,player,i))
            return true;
    return false;
}

private static boolean checkRow(int[][] array, int player, int index) {
    // check the row 'index'
}

// you could actually use a single method 
// checkRowOrCol(int[][] array, int player, int index, boolean isRow)
private static boolean checkCol(int[][] array, int player, int index) {
    // check the column 'index' 
}

private static boolean checkDiagonals(int[][] array, int player) {
    // check the diagonal and the anti-diagonal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You 're missing the rules to check if a row or a column is valid.

In order to check for a row, just maintain the first index as *constant* while moving through the elements of the second index. Something like this:

```
if (array[i][j] == array[i][j+1]) {
    //...
}
```

In order to check for a column, just maintain the second index as *constant* while moving through the elements of the first index. Something like this:

```
if (array[i][j] == array[i+1][j]) {
    //...
}
```

Implement this inside a `for` or another loop to go through all the rows or columns.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check diagonal, vertical and horizontal:

```
public static boolean winCheck(int[][] array, int player){
    int counterDiagonal = 1;
    int counterVertical = 1;
    int counterHorizontal = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        if (array[i][i] == array[i + 1][i + 1]) {
            counterDiagonal++;

        if (counterDiagonal == array.length) {
            System.out.println("Player " + player + " wins.");
            return true;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length - 1; j++) {
            if(array[i][j] == array[i][j + 1])
                counterVertical++;

            if (counterVertical == array.length) {
                System.out.println("Player " + player + " wins.");
                return true;
            }

            if(array[i][j] == array[i+1][j])
                counterHorizontal++;

            if (counterHorizontal == array.length) {
                System.out.println("Player " + player + " wins.");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(counterDiagonal);
    System.out.println(counterVertical);
    System.out.println(counterHorizontal);
}
```